# How to remove rabbiqmq queues which are showing as down

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbit cluster of 2 machines which I needed to migrate to new physical hardware.

I performed the migration by joining the 2 new severs to the cluster. Once all the connections had moved over I removed the old servers from the cluster.

I didn't realise that I had a few durable queues declared on the old servers which are now showing as down and I am unable to delete them.

When I try to delete the queues (through the admin tool as well as through code) I get the following error

```
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbit-1' of durable queue 'udq_1' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible", classId=50, methodId=30, cause=
```

I cannot bring the old servers back online since they have been decommissioned.

Is there a way I can delete these queues without having to reset the whole cluster?